# How can I show a non-public PDF file in browser?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, pdf

I've a bit of a problem. I'm currently build a service where people can sign a PDF in WordPress. For this, I'm using a template which is located in the public uploads folder from WordPress.

So before the user signs it, he can easily view this template in his browser via `https://www.my-site.de/wp-content/uploads/template.pdf`.

After he signed it, I'm creating a copy of this template with all relevant informations and moving it into a subfolder `signed-templates`:

```
$pdf->Output( 'F', wp_upload_dir()['basedir'] . '/signed-templates/123456.pdf' );
```

In the signed-template folder I've a `.htaccess` file with the following content to prevent public access via the browser:

```
deny from all
```

Now I'll come to my problem. The first user signed it and it's saved in the folder above. Now the second user needs to view and countersign it.

Before he can countersign it, I'll show him the file in the browser via a link. So how can I do this? I mean accessing vie the URL seems to be not possible because of the `.htaccess` file but this is required to prevent a leak of personal informations.

Each file has a unique id and this id is saved in my database. So the only information I have is the filename `123456.pdf` and the path to it.

Maybe it's an option to show it via AJAX? This would be the only idea I have.

Comment: Do you want a coded answer using PHP and related code or are you looking for a WordPress functional answer?

Comment: WordPress is written in PHP so PHP will work too. If you only know PHP, I can re-write it using WordPress functions like AJAX. The important's thing is to get this working.

Comment: My answer may be too complex for you if you're not a core PHP programmer

Comment: Ajax may be used but The concept I am running is to use a PHP interface file so that the browser never sees the true home of the PDF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MY approach to this that has been successfully used on various websites is:

**1)**
Create a PHP file that will load the data (*PDF*),

**2)**
The PHP is given some form of authentication (a *nonce key* value or similar database driven unique value)

**3)**
The PHP file accepts the authentication (such as a link from an email) and then loads the corresponding PDF from the protected directory.

The `.htaccess` prevents the *browser* from accessing files but as PHP is on the local file system, it can still load the PDF file and output it directly to the client browser as an anonymous "countersign.php" file. The User 2 will never know where on the server the PDF is actually stored (*and even if they did, they would not be able to directly access it*).

---

## Example

Directory Where PDF is stored is `/files/signed`
Directory of PHP file is `/countersign.php` 
Database will have `id (INT(8) A_I ) | filename (VARCHAR(255)) | nonce_code (VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE)`

Then once user 1 has signed - a Nonce (aka PRNG) code is generated and emails to User 2.

Example database row:

```
  id    |   filename   |               nonce_code
===========================================================
   4    |  123456.pdf  | AB463747CH567BC5456AB45023DBC36214
```

User 2 recieves an email with link:

> https://www.my-site.de/countersign.php?id=AB463747CF567BC5456AB45023DBC36214

The user clicks the link; the PHP will search for that link:

> **NOTE:** This below code block contains a fair bit of Summarised and Pseudo code - it's to illustrate the approach rather than the exact method that fits your criteria

```
$id = $_GET['id']; 
/***
 * DB check value is valid and do basic cleaning such as with a Hex checker. 
 * In this  example the nonce value is a Hex string but you can use your own system
 ***/
$dataBase = new dataBaseClass();

/***
 * Check database for this value and return the PDF string. 
 ***/ 
$result = $dataBase->prepare("SELECT filename FROM table WHERE nonce_code = :ncode ");
$result->execute([':ncode' => $id]);


/***
 * Now PHP loads the retrieved filename from the signed directory, 
 * and outputs it to the browser 
 ***/
$f = $result->fetch();
$file = wp_upload_dir()['basedir'] . '/signed-templates/'.'$f['filename'];
if(is_file($file)){
    /***
     * You should have a security, check that the file called is a PDF type 
     * (not shown here)
     ***/
    $output = file_get_contents(urlencode($file));
    if(!empty($output)){
        /***
         * PHP tells the browser it will act as if it is a PDF file:
         ***/
       header("Content-type: application/pdf");
       header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=filename.pdf");

       /***
        * The PDF will only be accessible to the user who loads the
        * page with the correct nonce code
        ***/
       print $output;  
    }
    else {
         // File error.
    }
}
else {
    // no file found.
    /***
     * Add a delay to throttle spam attempts to discover files
     * (various other practises can be employed depending on the required
     * security level)
     ***/
    sleep(2);
}
```

Once the PDF is counter signed you can update the database to clear the `nonce_code` value.

Comment: Wow, a cool approach. Thanks a lot Martin, I'll try to get this working now. I'll let u know when I got it or when I've some questions!

Comment: @Mr.Jo you can make it really smart using a `mod_rewrite`  to give: `https://www.my-site.de/countersign/AB463747CF567BC5456AB45023DBC36214` if you wish, as well, there is a lot of potential of smartening this up `:-)`

Comment: This is what I've thought, so I'll try my best :)